# Delete entries from a table based on multi-table conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

**Summary**: We need to delete entries from a table based on conditions involving the table itself as well as a separate table

I have been able to recreate the issue that we are trying to solve using two sample tables, called table_A and table_B.  Their definitions are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_A
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  date  DATE NOT NULL,
  otherFields_A VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  -- many other fields in the table (different from table_B)
  -- but not relevant to the question being asked

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);



CREATE TABLE table_B
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  date  DATE NOT NULL,
  otherFields_B VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  -- many other fields in the table (different from table_A)
  -- but not relevant to the question being asked

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The tables are populated as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table_A(name, date) VALUES('John Doe', '2018-01-01'), ('John Doe', '2018-07-01'), ('John Doe', '2018-12-01'), ('Mary Smith', '2018-08-02'), ('Andy Roberts', '2018-07-02'), ('John Doe', '2018-12-02');

INSERT INTO table_B(name, date) VALUES('Keith Miller', '2018-01-03'), ('Mary Smith', '2018-07-02'), ('John Doe', '2018-07-30');
```

We want to traverse table_A and delete all entries for which

```
table_B.name= table_A.name
AND
table_B.date >= table_A.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should as simple as :

```
DELETE table_A
FROM table_A
INNER JOIN table_B 
    ON table_B.id = table_A.id
    AND table_B.date >= table_A.date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cUSwDf9EBdPr5sKGr2WtgU/1)**

**Reference** : [Multiple-Table in `DELETE` Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: My apologies for the careless mistake.  It was name, not cik.  Your solution solution has worked for me.  Kindly update your answer (to correct my mistake)

Comment: The response from @GMB works perfectly.  However, due to an inadvertent error in my original post, the actual query should be **DELETE table_A FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON table_B.name = table_A.name AND table_B.date >= table_A.date;**